# How can I mount a docker config file with Skaffold?

Tags: kubernetes, skaffold

I want to use the [Prometheus](https://hub.docker.com/r/prom/prometheus/) image to deploy a container as part of the local deployment. Usually one has to run the container with [volume and bind-mount](https://prometheus.io/docs/prometheus/latest/installation/#volumes-bind-mount) to get the configuration file (`prometheus.yml`) into the container:

```
docker run \
    -p 9090:9090 \
    -v /path/to/prometheus.yml:/etc/prometheus/prometheus.yml \
    prom/prometheus
```

How can I achieve this with Kubernetes when using Skaffold?

Answer (score 2):

Your Kubernetes configuration will be something like this,
You can specify the port number and volume mounts. The important sections for mounting are `volumeMounts` and `volumes`.

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: my-prom
spec:
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: my-prom
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: my-prom
    spec:
      containers:
      - name: my-prom
        image: prometheus:latest
        resources:
          limits:
            memory: "128Mi"
            cpu: "500m"
        ports:
        - containerPort: 9090
        volumeMounts:
          - name: prom-config
            mountPath: /path/to/prometheus.yml
      volumes:
        - name: prom-config
          hostPath:
              path: /etc/prometheus/prometheus.yml
---
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: my-prom
spec:
  selector:
    app: my-prom
  ports:
  - port: 9090
    targetPort: 9090
```

save the Kubernetes config file in a folder and add below config to `skaffold.yaml` with the path to K8s config file,

```
deploy:
  kubectl:
    manifests:
    - k8s/*.yaml
```

Comment: And depending on your OS, you may need to do something additional work.  For example, to use Minikube on macOS, you'll need to mount your macOS filesystem into Minikube: https://minikube.sigs.k8s.io/docs/handbook/mount/

Comment: Right. I can remember when using Docker for Windows the filesystem paths paths have to be mounted via the UI as well.

Comment: @Bala I get `Are you trying to mount a directory onto a file (or vice-versa)? Check if the specified host path exists and is the expected type.`

Comment: As the file of interest is a config file I'm using `ConfigMap` instead.